# Scala Specs2 adding fragments dynamically

Tags: scala

During the building `org.specs2.Specification`,

I use adding briks like that:

```
 def is =  "My Spec".title ^ method1 ^ method2 ^ end
```

where methodN contains something like this:

```
a must be "expected string"
```

In my case I faced the problem that method2 depends from the execution of method2. Rephrasing that: method2 returns Fragment that must be postponed postponed until the the method1 finishing execution.

Are there any best practices for this?

Answer (score 0):

Regularly it should be written as follows:

```
def is =  "My Spec".title ^ "1" ! method1 ^ "2" ! method2 ^ end
```

But do you have an intention to do it your way instead?

Comment: Still id doesnt resolve deferrable execution of the Specification